# Remote JSON file is not loading each time - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a json file that is hosted on a server, I have used useEffect function to fetch JSON data but when that remote JSON is changed it does not reflect in app.

```
const themeStyleOnline = "https://someremote.website/theme.json";

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
     const [themeStyle2, setThemeStyle] = useState([]);

     useEffect(() => {
          fetch(themeStyleOnline)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => setThemeStyle(json))
           .catch((error) => alert(error)).finally(() => {
            console.log("THEME STYLE >>" + themeStyle2.statusbar); //THEME STYLE >> #7209b7 
     });

})
```

following is JSON in which value of statusbar is `#d00000`

```
{
  "statusbar":"#d00000",
  "header":"#560bad",
  "headertext":"#fffffc",
  "background":"#001219",
  "cardbg":"#ffba08",
  "titlebg":"#3f37c9",
  "titletext":"#fffffc"
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing one more `0` to be like this `#000000`

Comment: it's `#d00000` not `#000000`